# activeClassName for links with similar urls

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a list of links

```
<NavLink className="item" activeClassName="item-active" to="/url?filter=1">filter 1</NavLink>
<NavLink className="item" activeClassName="item-active" to="/url?filter=2">filter 2</NavLink>
<NavLink className="item" activeClassName="item-active" to="/url?filter=3">filter 3</NavLink>
```

My problem is that all links have the item-active classname.  is there a way to make it more specific? thank you

Comment: What forbids to just use a specific activeClassName for each of them ?

Comment: well.. activeClassName from react router allows me to add a specific class to the active link if the urls matches. since the url is too similar (it only changes the querystring) for some reason the same class is applied to all the links. (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/blob/master/lessons/05-active-links/README.md#active-class-name)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`isActive`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#isactive-func) prop to specify when a url is active.

```
const isUrlActive = (match, location) =>
  location.pathname + location.search === `/url${search}`;

  <NavLink
    className="item"
    activeClassName="item-active"
    to="/url?filter=1"
    isActive={isUrlActive}
  >filter 1</NavLink>
  <NavLink
    className="item"
    activeClassName="item-active"
    to="/url?filter=2"
    isActive={isUrlActive}
  >filter 2</NavLink>
  <NavLink
    className="item"
    activeClassName="item-active"
    to="/url?filter=3"
    isActive={isUrlActive}
  >filter 3</NavLink>
```

Ref: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5379

Answer (score 0):

In the [NavLink documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md) there are two props that could be useful :

- `exact`: it looks like a good candidate but reading further in the [Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool) (as it is supposed to work the same way) it states that being true or false, the matching works only on the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) part of the url.
- `isActive` : it lets you write an extra matching behavior. That's where you'll be able to check the query part (the one after the `?` symbol) of the location and whether it matches the component `to` prop or not. Inspect the two parameters *match* and *location* and you'll probably find matter there to do it.